# Converting a connection to a hidden WiFi network to a normal connection and back

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

In Windows 7 there is a checkbox in WiFi connection properties:

**Connect even if the network is not broadcasting**

Using this checkbox I can easily create connection to a hidden network, then go to the settings later, untick the checkbox and computer will not transmit connection requests to this network unless it is broadcasting.

In Windows 10 I didn't find this checkbox. It seems that in order to convert connection type I should delete it and create a new one. Some people suggest to remove the "Connect automatically" mark, but it is not the same.

Actually each WiFi connection should have two settings:

- Connect even if the network is not broadcasting
- Connect automatically

and each of 4 combinations of those flags should be possible.

Am I right that I should delete a connection and create a new one to change it from connecting to a hidden network to connecting to a network with a normally broadcasted SSID?

(Actually I have the same question about modern Android and iOS).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 OS,

- O
  [image: Adding WiFi Connection in Windows 10]
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, type `wi` and select *Wi-Fi settings*.
- Click *Manage known networks*.
- In the *Wi-Fi* dialog, click *Add a new network*.

  Fill in the boxes with details: *Security type* (likely *WPA2-Personal* for a home network), hidden *Network name* and *Security key*.

  Check *Connect automatically*.

  **Check** *Connect even if this network is not broadcasting*.

**There is no need to delete any *valid* existing connection.** Voilà, c'est fini! (Or if you listen to classical music on Wi-Fi, "Viola, c'est fini.")